# How to set background color in typescript?

Tags: css, typescript, background-color

How to set background color using classname in typescript of below code??

```
abc.innerHTML = abc.innerHTML.replace(element,'<span class="classname">text</span>');
```

Comment: you can't set background color using `classname`, unless you have a class that sets background color. Do you have such class? and which element do you want to set background color to?

Comment: I want the text inside span element to be colored. @Maximus

Comment: see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42527620/2545680), if it helped, consider accepting it

Answer (score 3):

You can do it the same way as in JS but the cast to `<HTMLElement>` [is required](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3263):

```
var def = "Maximus";
var li = document.querySelectorAll("#id li");
for (var i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
  var element = li[i];
  element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML.replace(def, '<span class="classname">text</span>');
  let spanEl = <HTMLElement>element.querySelector('span.classname');
  spanEl.style.color = 'orange';
}
```

Comment: [ts] Property 'style' does not exist on type 'NodeListOf<Element>'. @Maximus

Comment: weird !! tsconfig.json?? whats there to change? @Maximus

Comment: @coder, I've updated the answer. It should work now. Check and let me know if you still have a problem

Comment: Its throwing "Type 'NodeListOf<Element>' cannot be converted to type 'HTMLElement'." @Maximus

Comment: Typescript 2.2.1 @Maximus

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136958/discussion-between-maximus-and-coder).

Comment: what is `li`? show the code where it's defined. I'm tyring to understand the type of `li`

Comment: just pass the list elements, then you will know the errors.Try to work on visual code .@Maximus

Comment: @coder, I showed you that there is no error if I paste the code into TypeScript playground. So either you have incorrect configuration or you're not showing the full code. Or you're using incorrect version of the `tsc`.